# Understanding multi-fields to analyze the text once per language

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm implementing an analyzer for my ES, and I'm trying to understand the multi-fields to analyze the text once per language, as my document can have multiple languages.

```
"properties": {
    "body" : {
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
            "fr": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "french"
            },
            "en": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "es": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "spanish"
            },
            "de": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "german"
            },
            "pt": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "portuguese"
            },
            "nl": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "dutch"
            },
            "dk": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "danish"
}}}}
```

How does this really work? There's no further info in [ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mixed-lang-fields.html#_analyze_multiple_times).

For example, if If I try to index the string `Hello, my car is red`, the analyzers examines it in all languages until it detects its in english, so it creates the inverted index using `english` analyzer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzers' job is simply to *analyze* - they cannot *detect* anything.

The [multi field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html) allows to analyze the same value in different ways. In your example, the value you pass in the body field will be stored in each *sub*field after having been analyzed by the analyzer you specified.

As a simple example, just imagine you have two analyzers

```
  "analyzer":{
    "standard":{
      "type":"custom",
      "tokenizer":"standard",
      "filter":[
        "lowercase"
      ]
    },
    "low-keyword": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "keyword"
    }
  }
```

you can than specify a mapping similar to what you provided

```
"properties": {
    "body" : {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "standard"
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

so that when indexing "*This is a Test*", text will be stored like so

```
body: "this", "is", "a", "test"
body.keyword: "This is a Test"
```

There is no functionality in Elasticsearch that can detect languages and analyze text accordingly. There's an entire chapter about languages in the [definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/language-intro.html), if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: I see. So for each string I will have stored another string with the analyzer of each language (`body.en`, `body.es`, etc). So, when I try to make a search, this doesnt influence in the performance? I mean, there are a lot of `body.X` where `X` is each language where `ES` has to search for each query.

Comment: When you perform any query, you will have to specify which field you want to search on, i.e. when you perform a match query on the `body` field, you are NOT searching over the `body.en` field. Using multi fields only has an impact on the size of the index as you obviously store much more information.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't specify a field (`body.en`, `body.es`, etc) on the query as the user can have `body`s in many different language (one body in english, other body in spanish). So the only way I see to archieve this goal is to seach in all language fields (`body.en`, `body.es`, etc) which is a extreme lose of performance. Any solutions to fix this?